# Gaussian volterra process. Conditional distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation

Asssuming a probability space $(\Omega,(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0},\mathbb{P})$ such that $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is generated by a Brownian motion $W_t$. We assume that $s>0$ is fixed and $t\in[s,s+\Delta]$, where $\Delta>0$ is finite. I am trying to figure out the conditional distribution of the following process 
$$\int_{s}^t \frac{dW_u}{(t-u)^{\gamma}}\bigg|\mathcal{F}_s$$

where $0<\gamma<1/2 $. In this case, Itô's lemma does not apply because the process

$$\int_{s}^t \frac{dW_u}{(t-u)^{\gamma}}$$
is not a Itô diffusion. Moreover, the singularity of the kernel function at $t$ does not help either, any approach I have tried seems to fail at some point.

However my intuition tells me that 
$$\int_{s}^t \frac{dW_u}{(t-u)^{\gamma}}\bigg|\mathcal{F}_s\sim N\left(0,\frac{(t-s)^{1-2\gamma}}{1-2\gamma}\right)$$
since the Brownian $W_t$ seems not to be affected by the filtration $\mathcal{F}_s$.

I would appreciate any help to determine if there exists an analitical solution

Many thanks!

Comment: Since the integrand is in $L^2$, the integral is well defined. your distribution makes sense.

Comment: That is what I thought. Moreover, intuitively if I consider a forward euler approximation it does make sense.